# Как правильно организовать событие в listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Kак правильно пробросить событие, чтобы оно открывало при двойном клике на сроке в `listview` папку с файлом?

Как открыть папку с файлом знаю, вопрос как организовать событие. У меня пути получаются в переборе коллекции. Не знаю как вытащить их для события. Вот что есть:

```
// сам класс где создаются данные для отображения.
public class Controller
{
    public  List<info> PrintKeys(string rkey)
    {
        List<info> stroka=new List<info>();
        bool F = true;
        bool G = true;
        String rp = rkey;
        RegistryKey rk;
        using (rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(rp))
        {
            var e = rk.GetValueNames().Select(n => new
            {
                Name = n,
                Value = rk.GetValue(n),
                Exec = rk.GetValue(n).ToString()
                    .Split('"').Where(i => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).First()
            });
            foreach (var x in e)
            {
                var icon1 = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(x.Exec).ToBitmap();
                stroka.Add(new info() { A = icon1, F1 = F,G1 = G,Namefile1 = x.Name, Path1 = x.Value});
            }
        }
        return stroka;
    }
}

//вот класс самой формы
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Controller c=new Controller(); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        string r1 = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; // реестр local mashin
        string r2 = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; //реестр СCurren user
        string rp3 = @".DEFAULT\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; //реестр user 

        List<info> a = c.PrintKeys(r1);

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(a[i].Namefile1);
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add((string) a[i].Path1);
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(a[i].F1.ToString());
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(a[i].G1.ToString());


        }
    }
}

//И сам класс для данных
public class info
{
    public Bitmap A { get; set; } // иконка файла
    public string Namefile1 { get; set; } //Имя исполняемого файла.
    //public string C1 { get; private set; } //Параметры командной строки для запуска файла.
    public object Path1 { get; set; }// путь
    public bool F1 { get; set; }//Флаг наличия цифровой подписи.
    public bool G1 { get; set; }//Флаг корректности цифровой подписи

    public info() { }
}
```

Comment: Нужно событие `ListView.ItemActivate` и свойство `ListView.SelectedItems`. У вас же айтемы содержат путь, вот и читайте его из свойств айтема в обработчике события. Активированный айтем обязательно будет в коллекции `SelectedItems`

Comment: @rdorn Спасибо помогло